# how to i search in my whole index without giving fields in elasticsearch-kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

```
 GET my_production_productsd/_search
 {
 "query": {
  "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "ProductDescription": "women"
  }
  }
 }
```

it gets results from only `ProductDescription`

Comment: i have close to 10 fields and 1.5 lakh products in my index, i want to search with any term or keyword the whole index.

Comment: maybe looking for this one? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Comment: @MrSimple tried give 0 results

Comment: can you give some example records?

Comment: one of the record-           "_index": "my_production_productsd",
        "_type": "productsd",
        "_id": "15358",
        "_score": 5.968703,
        "_source": {
          "ProductId": "15358",
          "Productname": "Samsung 1.5 Ton 3 Star Split AC  - Morning Glory Violet(AR18JC3JAMV, Copper Condenser)",
          "ProductDescription": "",
          "FK_CategoryId": "7",
          "CategoryName": "Air conditioners",
          "CategoryUniquename": "air-conditioners",
          "FK_BrandId": "678",
          "BrandName": "Samsung",
          "BrandUniqueName": "samsung"

Comment: have you tried using wildcards too? It will make the query slower but it should work. For example "*women*"

Comment: The comment formatting makes the word italic but there are * marks at the start and end of the word.

Comment: but i have to give a field name for that right?

Comment: In this example you can see that query_string can work without field: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html

Comment: yeah it works .big thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on [`_all`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) field. It was deprecated in 6.0.0 version of ES mostly [because of storage size](https://www.elastic.co/blog/minimize-index-storage-size-elasticsearch-6-0). But you can still enable it. Maybe in your case it would not be a problem.

Example code:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": "john smith 1970"
    }
  }
}
```